# Not sure of the Print Structure with YouTube v3 API

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, google-api, youtube-api

So I was creating a script to list information from Google's V3 YouTube API and I used the structure that was shown on their Site describing it, so I'm pretty sure I'm misunderstanding something.

I tried using the structure that was shown to print JUST the Video's Title as a test

[image: PrintStructure]

and was expecting that to print, however it just throws an error. Error is below

[image: Error]

Here's what I wrote below

```
import sys, json, requests

vidCode = input('\nVideo Code Here: ')

url = requests.get(f'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&id={vidCode}&key=(not sharing the api key, lol)')
text = url.text

data = json.loads(text)

if "kind" in data:
    print(f'Video URL: youtube.com/watch?v={vidCode}')
    print('Title: ', data['snippet.title'])
else:
    print("The video could not be found.\n")
```

This did not work, however if I change `snippet.title` to just something like `etag` the print is successful.

I take it this is because the Title is further down in the JSON List.

[image: ExampleHere]

I've also tried doing `data['items']` which did work, but I also don't want to output a massive chunk of unformatted information, it's not pretty lol.

Another test I did was `data['items.snippet.title']` to see if that was what I was missing, also no, that didn't work.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is thet title is inside items that is an array. So you should iterate "items" or get the first item with something like items[0].title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to access the keys in the dictionary separately.

```
import sys, json, requests

vidCode = input('\nVideo Code Here: ')

url = requests.get(f'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&id={vidCode}&key=(not sharing the api key, lol)')
text = url.text

data = json.loads(text)

if "kind" in data:
    print(f'Video URL: youtube.com/watch?v={vidCode}')
    
    print('Title: ', data['items'][0]['snippet']['title'])
else:
    print("The video could not be found.\n")
```

To be clear, you need to access the 'items' value in the dictionary which is a list, get the first item from that list, then get the 'snippet' sub object, then finally the title.

Comment: Omg thank you. I was assuming it was something like this, but I didn't know the exact syntax to do it with.